# Can websocket.send() and websocket.recv() be in different connections?

Tags: python, websocket

I need to send message to the websocket server from anywhere in my program, and constantly receive messages from the server and call the listeners.

I am using the python `websockets` library.

Here is the code I plan to use, but I am not sure this will work because `send` and `recv` are using different websocket connections.

```
import asyncio
import websockets

# Listeners to handle received data
listeners = []

# Function to add listeners
def add_listener(listener):
    listeners.append(listener)

# Function to remove listeners
def remove_listener(listener):
    listeners.remove(listener)

# Function to handle received messages
def handle_message(message):
    # Send the received message to all listeners
    for listener in listeners:
        listener(message)

# Function to send a message
async def send_message(message):
    async with websockets.connect('ws://your-websocket-url') as websocket:
        await websocket.send(message)

# Function to receive messages
async def receive_messages():
    async with websockets.connect('ws://your-websocket-url') as websocket:
        while True:
            message = await websocket.recv()
            handle_message(message)

# Start the message receiver in the background
async def start_receiver():
    await receive_messages()

# Function to start the WebSocket connection
def start_websocket():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(start_receiver())

# Example usage:
def my_listener(message):
    print("Received message:", message)

add_listener(my_listener)
start_websocket()

# Send a message from outside the scope
asyncio.run(send_message("Hello, server!"))
```

If I `send` message in one connection, will the server response go to `recv` which is in another connection?